# How to access Tomcat from external ip

Tags: web-applications, xampp, tomcat7, windows-firewall, port80

I want to show a friend from far my Tomcat stuff. So, I tried to make my Tomcat accessible to external ip. And, of course - that's why I'm here ;-) - it didn't work.

The XAMPP 3.2.2 runs on win7 in a LAN.

I tried the following steps:

**Router:**

- set ip static
- portforwarding for Tomcat ports

**Firewall:allowed access for**

- Commons Daemon Service Manager
- Apache HTTP Server

**extended options**

- opend Apache HTTP Server to private and public
- opend Commons Doemon Service Manager to private public
- opend the ports for Tomcat

**cmd:**

- "netstat -an" showed me that port 8080 is listening

**software:**

- uninstalled VM Ware

**tomcat:**
I read a lot of stuff about Tomcat configuration. I got the impression, that by default one can access Tomcat from outside. Setting up contexts is much more to develop a more detailled regulation; at least I didn't find sth. about this in tutorials.

**server.xml**
 - installed host "dummytest" in addition to localhost in server.xml; and also pasted this in the win host file 127.0.0.1 dummyhost

- set resolveHosts="true"

The thing is: I can access the Apache (on port 80) but not the Tomcat

Comment: Step forward: As port80 worked for Apache I changed "Connector port="8080"" to "Connector port="80"" in the server.xml; restarted tomcat on xampp; xampp didn't recognized the start; but my browser did - an so did the browser from an external ip! Apparently there is a problem with the ports but I still have no idea what else I could change to make the port 8080 work.

Comment: And it also worked for 8010.

Comment: I just disactivated the firewall rule for port opening and it still works.